# Android Studio Core Dump

Tags: java, android, performance, ubuntu-14.04

I have working with Android Studio for quite a long time. Today, I have upgraded my android studio's some of the build tools as well as upgraded to a latest version (1.5 or so), I can't create any more new project. I am getting a core dump error. I am from Ubuntu 14.04, I am running it from my terminal.

Here is the Error terminal is giving me

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f1520266ca8, pid=4094, tid=139728681764608
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x436ca8]     FreeListSpace_DCTOC::walk_mem_region_with_cl_par(MemRegion, HeapWord*, HeapWord*, FilteringClosure*)+0x268
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/monkey/Code/core or core.4094 
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/monkey/java_error_in_STUDIO_4094.log 
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I did a little googling and found out that it might happen if my Java runs out of memory. So, I went up and gave Java unlimited memory (it has basic 382MB or something memory). I have been in this error for whole day long.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to downgrade libglib2.0-0 from synaptic. and don't forget to lock the downgrade version, so it will not update again in the future.

downgrade:
package -> force version

lock:
package -> lock version